# Python / assign tuple

Tags: python

I have the following code in python:

```
stage = OrderedDict([('a', '5678), ('b', '56')])

log.info("1")
log.info(stage.items()[0][1])
stage.items()[0] = ('a', '1234')
log.info("2")
log.info(stage.items()[0][1])
log.info("3")
```

It prints the following:

```
1
5678
2
5678
3
```

This althought I assign to `stage.items()[0][1]` the value `1234`.

`stage` is an `OrderedDict`, like this: `OrderedDict([('a', '5678), ('b', '56')])`

What can be the reason for that?

Comment: @Tichodroma: I edit the question. sorry.

Comment: Most likely `stage.items()` is returning a new list/dict/whatever each time it's called, so modifying the result of one call wouldn't affect the result of a subsequent call.  It's also not clear it's even safe to modify the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`OrderdDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#ordereddict-objects) are `dict`s. Members are access by key, not by positon:

```
stage = OrderedDict([('a', '5678'), ('b', '56')])
print(stage["a"])
stage["a"] = 'changed'
print(stage)
```

Output:

```
'5678'
OrderedDict([('a', 'changed'), ('b', '56')])
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, the best is to look at the exact code source for the `items` method of the OrderedDict:

```
def items(self):
        'od.items() -> list of (key, value) pairs in od'
        return [(key, self[key]) for key in self]
```

So reading that, it is very clear why changing an element of item will not change your dictionary. As I had assumed above, the function you are calling does not return a data memeber directly, but it rewrites the values of your dictionary in a list and returns that list.

Note that you can do the following:

```
d = OrderedDict({'a':[0]})
d.items()[0][1].append(1)
```

This will actually modify your list.

In your specific example, if you want to modify your dictionary, you can do the following:

```
d[d.keys()[0]] = 3
```